# best practice for setting PATH variable in nested user env

Tags: shell

In my user environment I/(macports) have set my PATH to be in the form of

`PATH=app1/bin:app2/bin/:...:$PATH`

However if I have nested shells the PATH variable gets concatenated all the time, of course this is not a major issue, but still, isn't there a better solution?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is simply that the PATH as-is is still valid for nested shells, i.e. we should not re-evaluate the PATH variable i.e. do not include this in `.bashrc|.zshrc`, but put this in `.profile|.zprofile`. Profile configs are run once for every login shell. In this context you can look at the profile configs as being an initial config.

Comment: If the TS' problem is similar, but the above solution is not viable, then @glennjackman is a very great solution code-wise

Answer (score 1):

You can check if that directory is already in the PATH pretty easily:

```
for dir in app1/bin app2/bin; do
    if [[ :"$PATH": != *:"$dir":* ]]; then
        PATH="$dir:$PATH"
    fi
done
```

It's looking for a colon-delimited directory within your PATH. Note that the asterisks need to be outside the quotes, as shown.

Another way to write it:

```
[[ :"$PATH": != *:app1/bin:* ]] && PATH="app1/bin:$PATH"
[[ :"$PATH": != *:app2/bin:* ]] && PATH="app2/bin:$PATH"
```